# regular expressing to find words contain letters

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression that will find all the words in a string that contain a part of that word? For example I need to find all the words that have 'ball' in them in a string like "baseball\nfootball\nsoccer\nballsport\njunkballjunk\n"

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution using [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b\w*ball\w*\b
```

The anchors ensure that only entire words are matched. `\w*` matches any number of alphanumeric characters (letters, digits and underscores), so it does not strictly match "words", but is a good enough approximation for most cases.

If you want to be more specific, you can use `[^\W\d_]` instead of `\w` to only allow letters.